# Having trouble converting Python app to script I can run

Tags: python

I have a python script that I made to do some file validation at work - I made it using Anadconda3 and the Spyder IDE.  No real reason I used that IDE, it's just how I started learning Python and it's what I know.

I made it on my work computer and our machines are SUPER locked down.  I can't even run pip install commands on CMD due to the firewall blocking such requests.

I'm ready to deploy this code to be run, I'll be using AWA to trigger the job to run and AWA can trigger anything -  batch file, EXE, even a .py file.  The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get my libraries and dependencies included with my file to get the file to run.

py2exe and pyinstaller won't run as they can't download or run pip install to add necessary modules.  When I make a .bat file and call my .py file I get a numpy import error.  I also can't use py2exe or pyinstaller on another machine because I'll have no way to transfer over the final file.

I think the best bet is to have a filepath for the import statements in my .py file and I can edit it when I push to production but I'm unsure how to do that.

Any other thoughts are welcome, thanks!

Edit: Here is the error I get when trying to run the batch file that calls my .py file:

> C:\Users\LCVM2Q\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:138:
> UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R)
> MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under
> condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is
> not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see
> http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service   from . import
> *distributor_init Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\LCVM2Q.spyder-py3\BDW to Stucky Validation.py", line 2, in
>
> import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\LCVM2Q\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init**.py", line
> 16, in 
> raise ImportError( ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.8 from
>   "C:\Users\LCVM2Q\Anaconda3\python.exe"   * The NumPy version is:
>   "1.19.2"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath:
> The specified module could not be found.
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You wouldn't use a filepath in import statements. Rather, you could edit the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Comment: @OneCricketeer - after reading, it sounds like that's something I shouldn't need to edit which makes me think my error is another issue.

Comment: Adding the error I get when trying to run my file into the original question

Comment: Well, numpy requires compiled C modules installed. If you cannot install anything at all, that might be somewhat difficult

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I'm able to download some bz2 files and install at the command line.  I did that to test py2exe and pyinstaller but both of them needed to download more files to work but couldn't.